# onDidChangeActiveTextEditor not working for custom text editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to use the `vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` API to get notified when the active text editor changes. This works fine for standard editors but does not get invoked for a custom text editor.

To reproduce the problem I tested using this sample: [custom-editor-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/custom-editor-sample)

I edited [extension.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/custom-editor-sample/src/extension.ts) so the `activate` methods looks like this:

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    // Register our custom editor providers
    context.subscriptions.push(CatScratchEditorProvider.register(context));
    context.subscriptions.push(PawDrawEditorProvider.register(context));

    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor((editor) => {
        console.log("Active Editor Changed: " + editor?.document.fileName);
    }));
}
```

If I open the custom text editors registered by the sample the `onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` callback does not get invoked.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Thanks Mark

Comment: I don't know if I understood the question right. But I got a similar problem. Where the onDidChangeActiveTextEditor won't get triggered. The solution I found is to add  `"activationEvents": ["onStartupFinished"],` in the package.json.